# Need regular expression help for special matching of string for html 5 pattern attribute

Tags: regex, html

I have been trying to find a regular expression to match requirements I need, and have had no luck so far.

I am currently trying the following regex to allow for these email rules:

```
@@test@address.com
test@address.com
test@address.com@


   var email = "@@test@test.com"; //needs to also regular email or 2 @ symbols in front or trailing
   var patt = new RegExp("^\@{0,2}\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*@{0,2}​‌‌​​$");
   var res = patt.test(email);
```

The browser displays an error though stating that "\" is an invalid character for the starting of a code block.

Comment: We did see the same question yesterday - why are you still trying to validate nonsense email adresses ? With this requirement, you could very easily come up with [**`^[\w.@]+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/oA2cK1/1). If this does not help, please specify your requirements further.

Comment: It is a test to modify the expression.

Comment: It is not something used in production. It is for a test, I am just good at regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks you, I will try the recommended answer you gave.

Comment: It is still not working properly. I have been testing it in w3schools regexp editor. Does the +s make it an optional rule?

Comment: See I thought this would say the first two character can be "@". ^@{0,2} Am I mistaken about this?

Comment: `^@{0,2}` matches 0 to 2 @ signs at the beginning of the string.

Comment: You don't need to escape the at sign `^\@` there. Post some code or something, why make people guess ?

Comment: The code is all above. I will post it as it is. I didn't think code as needed if the allowed scenarios are posted and the expression I am using. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^@{0,2}[\w-._]+@[\w-]+\.\w+@{0,2}$/
```

This expression matches all three of your examples. Let me know if this works, or if there are any other rules to follow.

Comment: Seems good, and thanks. I am not a reg expressions guy. Though I need to study it. Thanks again.